# PHP code executes before submit

Tags: php, execution

I made a login form, I had a lot of other problems with it and now I found out that the PHP code was being executed **before** the *submit*. HOW can the problem be solved? Since PHP does not support onclick events(which anyway sucks!), I don't see any solution that I know!

Code:

```
//Get the form with POST
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);



$usernames=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE Username='" . $_POST['user'] . "' AND Password='" . $_POST['pass'] . "'");
if(!$usernames){echo mysql_error();}

$count=mysql_num_rows($usernames);
if(!$count){echo mysql_error();}

//If $count is equal to one, register the user and redirect him to his page, or else   echo him that his info is wrong
if($count === 1) {
$_SESSION['code'] = "titan";
$_SESSION['ande'] = $user;
$_SESSION['password'] = $password;
header("location: home.php");}
else {
echo "<p style='color:red;text-align:center;'>Wrong username or password!</p>";}
```

Comment: PHP does not allow functions? I've been doing it wrong all these years!

Comment: `Since PHP does not allow functions` - really?

Comment: PHP allows functions.

Comment: Also, sanitize your SQL

Comment: Prepare to have your [mind blown](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php). I can't believe they finally added this in PHP 0.1!

Comment: Guys, all the snark is unhelpful and only serves to make stack overflow look like it's hostile to beginners. It's self-evident from the code that this is someone's first "my form in php" code. You guys should be better than this.

Comment: Sorry, I wanned to say "PHP doesn't allow **onclick events**!

Answer (score 5):

Wrap the code that is supposed to be executed after the form submission in an IF statement that checks to see if the form is submitted:

```
if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])
{
    // your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check if form is submitted

```
if(isset($_POST['user'])) {

   //Your php code goes here

}
```

---

**Based on your comment I extended this answer**

Just place all code in this condition which you have sent in your question

```
if(isset($_POST['user']))
{

    //Get the form with POST
    $user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);



    $usernames=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE Username='" . $_POST['user'] . "' AND Password='" . $_POST['pass'] . "'");
    if(!$usernames){echo mysql_error();}

    $count=mysql_num_rows($usernames);
    if(!$count){echo mysql_error();}

    //If $count is equal to one, register the user and redirect him to his page, or else   echo him that his info is wrong
    if($count === 1) {
    $_SESSION['code'] = "titan";
    $_SESSION['ande'] = $user;
    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
    header("location: home.php");}
    else {
    echo "<p style='color:red;text-align:center;'>Wrong username or password!</p>";}

}
```

Comment: It didn't work! Maybe I'm doing it wrong: Should I place this code as a new one or should I replace the old condition with this one?

Comment: You will get idea, see `login.php` page script from this answer 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18979508/2459296

Answer (score 0):

What I **DID NOT** tell you was that the PHP code was in the same file with the form and the rest of HTML... I tried to remake the code in AJAX, (it didn't work =(, but it still helped!)  and for that I moved the PHP code inside another file (`Login_engine.php`). And that was it!
 Sure, there still is a tiny problem: now, the red text is displayed inside `Login_engine.php`... That sucks!