# Displaying MySQL data to clients once they log in

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have tried numerous combinations of code to try and display my client data to them on their own profile page once they log in.

This is my first time designing a website and i have never worked with MySQL before but i have developed a quick understanding of how it all works.

I understand that i need to create sessions to 'store' their information when they log in then i can display it as i wish ?

Does anyone have any code that i could use?

My SQL info:

- db: taxretur_login
- table: members

aspects i would like to show:

- name
- email
- username

Thanks.
Stan.

UPDATE:

This code works and pulls all my table info accross to a users page but i only want data unique to that paticular user:

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = '';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'SELECT id_user, email, 
           name, username
    FROM members';

mysql_select_db('taxretur_login');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval))
{
echo "User ID :{$row['id_user']}  <br> ".
     "Email: {$row['email']} <br> ".
     "Name: {$row['name']} <br> ".
     "Username : {$row['username']} <br> ".
     "--------------------------------<br>";
}  
echo "Fetched data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Did you know how to use database in php?

Comment: Yes i understand how to use the database in php.

Comment: Look at this answer on how to properly use mysqli: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18196311/1948292

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create members table in your database

```
CREATE TABLE `members` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` char(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` char(30) NOT NULL,
  `email` char(40) NOT NULL,
  `pass` char(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Add an user into table members

```
INSERT INTO `members` VALUES ('1', 'user1', 'mr. x', 'email@domain.com', '123');
```

---

Just change the variable as your mysql user in page connection.php

connection.php

```
<?php
$mysql_host = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_pass = "";
$mysl_database = "taxretur_login";

$conn = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass);
mysql_select_db($mysl_database, $conn);
?>
```

login.php

```
<?php
include("connection.php");

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $pass = $_POST["pass"];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM members 
            WHERE username='$username' AND pass='$pass'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $numRows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($numRows==1) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
        header("Location: ./profile.php");
    } else {
        echo "Invalid Login Information";   
    }
}
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>" method="post">
<table>
<tr><td>User Name</td><td><input type="text" name="username" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password</td><td><input type="password" name="pass" /></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

profile.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include("connection.php");

$username = $_SESSION["username"];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$username'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $username = $row["username"];
    $name = $row["name"];
    $email = $row["email"];

    echo "
    <table>
        <tr><td>User Name</td><td> : </td><td>$username</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Name</td><td> : </td><td>$name</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Email</td><td> : </td><td>$email</td></tr>
    </table>
    ";
}
?>
```

Comment: I know, but all time I have seen many users always want this but they did not get it from us, so I have tried to do just one time.

Comment: @DanFromGermany, Best observation, It was in mind but I wanted it simple for a fresher like me. Thanks.

Comment: All my login and connection files are already setup. so i cant just setup those files. My login.php form states: form id='login' action='<?php echo $fgmembersite->GetSelfScript(); ?>' so it looks like it runs the login from there? Is that correct?  I have no idea what to do

Answer (score 1):

You should try yourself first, help is here. database connection with select statement and print first name 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-select-query.htm

Comment: should be in comments :)

Comment: @Naveen, you have edited, but removed one of the link. I had posted 2 linked for help.

Comment: You have posted w3schools, please read about w3schools here http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: Rajiv, i have used a set code to pull data from my table successfully ! Thanks. BUT i want to only pull 1 paticular user data.

Comment: @StanHowe select name, email, username from members where username = 'username';

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your user has a user id (uid), you should be able to fetch information from the database, relative to their said 'uid'.

An example query would look something like:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, email FROM `users` WHERE `id` = 'UID_HERE';
```

If your table had firstname, lastname & email fields/columns in it.

Definitely look into using [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) to do all database work, because mysql_ is no longer being developed.

Comment: Where you have 'UID_HERE' is this relative to my column name in my table? and 'users' would be my table name?

Comment: @StanHowe well it would be the logged in users' id in the database.

Comment: I want it so it pulls in each users info, wouldnt that mean i would have to manually enter their id's?

Comment: I dont understand. You want to show all the users? Or user specific data ?

Comment: User specific data. They can login and view a page that only they can see (i have all this working.) i just want their own page to show their 'account' information (including username, email, full name etc)

Comment: Then you should do it by their ID, thats the easiest way to grab the information. the UID_HERE would be in a session variable once they login correctly. What session variables do you set?

Comment: I dont have any session variables set, i have tried various bits of code and couldnt get it to work. On my login.php i have my login form. Would i set my session variables here?

Comment: Your best bet is to set a session with the users ID, and then use it to run the query i showed you above.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your query

```
$sql = 'SELECT id_user, email, name, username
          FROM members';
```

to

```
$sql = "SELECT id_user, email, name, username
          FROM members where id_user = '$dbuser'";
```